ROS file structure
Can someone please explain the ROS2 file structure.
I am trying to build a package and I am not sure how to approach the following problem.
I have a c program that should use a file for config data (read/write). Where to store it and what do I need to do to make it as a part of the package?

You can store the file in a params folder in your package. You then need to install the directory in the cmake file. Your cmake should look something like this.
install(DIRECTORY params DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

You can then access this file in your code from the pkg share.
#include <ament_index_cpp/get_package_share_directory.hpp>
std::string package_share_directory = ament_index_cpp::get_package_share_directory("my_package_name");

